# Issue creating map shading in Matplotlib imshow by setting opacity to data gradient

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient, opacity, pixel-shading

I am trying to add shading to a map of some data by calculating the gradient of the data and using it to set alpha values.

I start by loading my data (unfortunately I cannot share the data as it is being used in a number of manuscripts in preparation. **EDIT - December, 2020: the published paper is available with open access on the Society of Exploration Geophysicists [library](https://library.seg.org/doi/epdf/10.1190/tle34080948.1), and the [data is available](https://github.com/seg/tutorials-2015/blob/master/1508_Mapping_and_validating_lineaments/continued.txt) with an accompanying [Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/seg/tutorials-2015/blob/master/1508_Mapping_and_validating_lineaments/1508_Mapping_and_validating_lineaments.ipynb)):**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import imread, imshow, gray, mean
import matplotlib.colors as cl
%matplotlib inline 

data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
plt.imshow(data, cmap='cubehelix')
plt.show()
```

gets me a plot of the data:
[image: data]

Then I calculate the total horizontal gradient and normalize it to use for shading:

```
dx,dy = np.gradient(data, 1, 1)
tdx=np.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
tdx_n=(tdx-tdx.min())/(tdx.max()-tdx.min())
tdx_n=1-tdx_n
```

which looks as I expected:

```
plt.imshow(tdx_n[4:-3,4:-3],  cmap='bone')
plt.show()
```

[image: gradient]

To create the shading effect I thought I would get the colour from the plot of the data, then replace the opacity with the gradient so as to have dark shading proportional to the gradient, like this:

```
img_array = plt.get_cmap('cubehelix')(data[4:-3,4:-3])
img_array[..., 3] = (tdx_n[4:-3,4:-3]) 
plt.imshow(img_array)
plt.show()
```

But the result is not what I expected:
[image: shading]

This is what I am looking for (created in Matlab, colormap is different):
[image: shading Matlab]

Any suggestion as to how I may modify my code?

UPDATED

With Ran Novitsky's method, using the code suggested in the answer by titusjan, I get this result:
[image: pegtop]

which gives the effect I was looking for. In terms of shading though I do like titusjan's own suggestion of using HSV, which gives this result:
[image: titusjans].

However, I could not get the colormap to be cubehelix, even though I called for it:

```
from matplotlib.colors import rgb_to_hsv, hsv_to_rgb
hsv = rgb_to_hsv(img_array[:, :, :3])
hsv[:, :, 2] = tdx_n
rgb = hsv_to_rgb(hsv)
plt.imshow(rgb[4:-3,4:-3], cmap='cubehelix')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Matplotlib includes a [hill shading](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LightSource.shade) implementation. This calculates the intensity by comparing the gradient with a light source at a certain angle. So it's not exactly what you are implementing, but close and may even give better results.

Ran Novitsky has made [another hill shading implementation](http://rnovitsky.blogspot.nl/2010/04/using-hillshade-image-as-intensity.html) that differs from Matplotlib in the way how the color and intensity values are merged. I can't tell which is better but it's worth a look.

Perhaps the best way of combining color and intensity would be to use *gouraud shading*, which is used in 3D computer graphics. My own approach, which I have implemented in the past, was to put the intensity in the *value* layer of the HSV color of the image.

I don't think I agree with your approach of placing the intensity (`tdx_n` in your case) in the alpha layer of the image. This means that where the gradient is low the image will be transparent and you will see data that was plotted earlier. I think that's what's happening in your screen shot.

Furthermore I think you need to normalize your data before you pass it through the cmap, just as you normalize your intensity:

```py
data_n=(data-data.min())/(data.max()-data.min())
img_array = plt.get_cmap('cubehelix')(data_n)
```

We then can use the approach of Ran Novitsky to merge the color with the intensity:

```py
rgb = img_array[:, :, :3]

# form an rgb eqvivalent of intensity
d = tdx_n.repeat(3).reshape(rgb.shape)

# simulate illumination based on pegtop algorithm.
rgb = 2 * d * rgb + (rgb ** 2) * (1 - 2 * d)

plt.imshow(rgb[4:-3,4:-3])
plt.show()
```

Or you can follow my past approach and put the intensity in the *value* layer of the HSV triplet.

```py
from matplotlib.colors import rgb_to_hsv, hsv_to_rgb

hsv = rgb_to_hsv(img_array[:, :, :3])
hsv[:, :, 2] = tdx_n
rgb = hsv_to_rgb(hsv)
plt.imshow(rgb[4:-3,4:-3])
plt.show()
```

**Edit 2015-05-23:**

Your question has prompted me to finish my hill shading implementation that I started a year ago. I've put it on Github [here](https://github.com/titusjan/hill_shading).

It uses a blending mechanism that is similar to Gouraud shading, which is used in 3D computer graphics. It's labeled *RGB blending* below. I think this is the best blending algorithm, HSV blending gives erroneous results when the color is close to black (note the blue color in the center of the HSV image, which is not present in the un-shaded data).

RGB blending is also the simplest algorithm, it just multiplies the intensity with the RGB triplet (it adds an extra dimension of length 1 to allow broadcasting in the multiplication).

```
rgb = img_array[:, :, :3]
tdx_n_exp = np.expand_dims(tdx_n, axis=2) 
result = tdx_n_exp * rgb
plt.imshow(result[4:-3,4:-3])
```

[image: blending comparison results]

Comment: I am trying to use total horizontal derivative for the shading as it will enhance features based on their gradient, hence independently from the direction of light source. I will try your recommendations with this dataset and report back on results.

Comment: Our brains are wired to interpret shading as shadows cast by a light source so I think hill shading will be more intuitive. Yes the light source is arbitrary but as long as it comes from the top it doesn't matter (if the light comes from below we will interpret hills as valleys and vice versa)

Comment: It was late yesterday so I didn't have time to put in my old approach of using the _value_ layer of HSV. I've added it to my answer now.

Comment: I will try these tomorrow. I tried HSV before but again was not getting what I was expecting, I will certainly try your approach as well. Have you ever used 3 datasets?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by using three datasets, so I guess not.

Comment: I accepted your answer. You provide two working methods, which is great. Could you suggest a modification to your own method so that a different colormap can be used (e.g. cubehelix)? I am not sure I understand why it does not work with just specifying it.

Comment: PS my comment about light source has to do with the fact that in many geophysical applications the lighting is selected as oblique and then rotated to highlight features with different orientation. But I prefer using the total horizontal gradient or a high pass filtered version of the data.

Comment: I've finished my hill shading implementation that I was working on last year and put in on Github [here](https://github.com/titusjan/hill_shading). I've included a better color blending (RGB) algorithm, see also my edit and screen shots above. You can reuse the `rgb_blending` and `color_data` functions to colorize your own intensities with the cubehelix color map. Take a look at the `hill_shade` function as a starting point. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: P.S. about the orientation of the light source. My implementation can illuminate the terrain will multiple light sources at once. This may be nice to experiment with. See the `demo_multi_source.py` example.